# Is there a Cocoa way to pass information between two sandboxed apps?

Tags: cocoa, ipc, nsnotificationcenter

I'm writing two sandboxed macOS apps that operate like a "server" and "client", in that one runs in the background with authoritative logic and data, and the other runs transiently in the foreground with a dummy view that will ask the background app what it should do.

The most promising prospect so far was [`DistributedNotificationCenter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/distributednotificationcenter), but I was deflated when I saw that [the documentation for posting 
a notification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/distributednotificationcenter/1418360-postnotificationname) says:

> #### Important
>
> Sandboxed apps can send notifications only if they do not contain a dictionary. If the sending application is in an App Sandbox, `userInfo` *must* be `nil`.

So it seems that `DistributedNotificationCenter` can only be used to send the notification's *name* across processes. How disappointing! It *does* say something about a `notificationInfo` dictionary, but not how to set that or use it, so I assume that's a typo meant to be `userInfo`.

True to its claim, even when I add the `com.apple.security.application-groups` entitlement to both apps with the same value for each, it fails when I try to call `postNotificationName` with a `userInfo` dictionary, printing the following to the console:

```
2017-07-26 11:45:44.168865-0400 Foreground App[49005:1967499] *** attempt to post distributed notification 'me.benleggiero.incomingBackgroundServerRequest' thwarted by sandboxing.
```

**Is there a Cocoa way to send arbitrary data between apps?** It doesn't necessarily have to be secure; I can ensure that independently. I'm just trying to avoid setting up sockets and other C stuff like that.

Comment: Take a look at [XPC Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingXPCServices.html)

Comment: You just need appropriate entitlements. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1888/_index.html

Comment: @vadian That says it uses GCD, but isn't that discouraged with things like `OperationQueue`?

Comment: @matt What do you mean? Documentation for DNC doesn't mention entitlements affecting its behavior

Comment: ??? OperationQueue _is_ GCD

Comment: @matt I see. I wasn't aware of that implementation detail.

Comment: @matt I see you updated your initial comment. I don't see in those links where it describes how entitlements affect `DistributedNotificationCenter`

Comment: @matt I've attempted your solution involving entitlements, but DNC still doesn't work. Question updated to elaborate.

Comment: Actually *sandboxed* and *doesn't necessarily have to be secure* is a contradiction in terms. ;-) You need to use secure patterns in sandboxed apps

Comment: @vadian Not really; _sandboxed_ just means _the app can't do damage without Apple's permission_. It doesn't mean _other processes can't hack their way into intercepting the app's data_. Either way, I take care of end-to-end security in the app anyway.